# Check if REST Response contains empty List

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client

to check if a `Person` exists I use a RESTful Resource which I access via GET like this:

```
GET http://api.my-site.com/persons?id=254
```

And I can get either this Response for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persons id="http://api.my-site.com/persons" size="2" offset="0" total="2">
    <person>
        <id>http://api.my-site.com/person/1</id>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>http://api.my-site.com/person/2</id>
    </person>
</persons>
```

If there are persons or I get this Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persons id="http://api.my-site.com/persons" size="0" offset="0" total="0"/>
```

If there are no persons.

I execute the GET in Java with `Jersey` like this:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
... 

boolean checkIfPersonExist(String uri){
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri);

    ClientResponse response = webResource
            .accept("application/xml")
            .get(ClientResponse.class);
    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Now I want to check if there are `Persons` in my `Response`. At the moment I do just check if `total="0"` is inside my `Response`.

```
    if (response.getStatus() == OK) {
        return !output.contains("total=\"0\"");
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

This works but I'm not satisfied with it because it does not really check if there persons but if this string exists or not.

Is there a better way doing this?
Maybe creating an `PersonListEntity` which can contain `Persons` and doing something like this:

```
PersonListEntity output = response.getEntity(PersonListEntity.class);
```

Is it even possible to have an `PersonListEntity` which can contain multiple or even no `Persons`?

Changing the behaviour of my RESTful Resource is no option for me unfortunately.

Comment: Why are you looking at the raw string? You can use Jackson to map the XML to a custom object and check the size of the list instead...

Comment: Parsing the string as XML and checking whats inside seems to be much better for me. If you want you can post your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking at the raw string in the response, you can use [Jersey's XML support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/xml.html) to automatically parse it and convert it to a POJO. Your POJO will contain a list of persons and you can simply check the size.